# Set ID's If Found in Array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, ecmascript-2016

I have a list of array called `productsList` and I also have an array called `chosenProducts`.
I want to see in the `setProducts` if ids of `chosenProducts` is found in `productsList`

**Expected Output**

```
[
    "AAA"
]
```

**productsList**

```
[
    {
        "id": "AAA",
    },
    {
        "id": "BBB",
    },
]
```

**chosenProducts**

```
[
    "AAA",
    "DDD"
]
```

**code**

```
setProducts([])
```

Comment: Use `Array.filter` to achieve the expected result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: `filter()` & `includes()` would be a great way to achieve your goal. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map and filter` those that items from productList that are in chosenProducts using `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.includes`

```js
var productList = [
    {
        "id": "AAA",
    },
    {
        "id": "BBB",
    },
]

var chosenProducts = [
    "AAA",
    "DDD"
]

var products = productList.reduce((acc, product) => {
  if(chosenProducts.includes(product.id)) {
     acc.push(product.id);
  }
 return acc;
}, []);
console.log(products);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
productsList.filter(product => chosenProducts.find(chosen => chosen === product.id)).map(product => product.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, will be better to change your product list to Mapping.
You can use JS Map, and save all data on Map after which you can easily check if item exist in the list or not with `has` method.

And in such kind of solution, you time complexity will be O(n) instead of O(n^2).

```
const productList=  [
    {
        "id": "AAA",
    },
    {
        "id": "BBB",
    },
]

const coosenProducts = [
    "AAA",
    "DDD"
]

const mapping = new Set()

productList.forEach(item => mapping.add(item.id)) // O(n)

const result = coosenProducts.filter(item => mapping.has(item)) // O(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter()` & `includes()` would be a great way to achieve your goal.

Here is the code:

```
const productList = [{"id": "AAA"}, {"id": "BBB"}]
const choosenProducts = ["AAA", "DDD"]

const result = productList.filter(product => {
    if (choosenProducts.includes(product.id)) return product
}).map(element => element.id)

setProducts(result)
```

Happy coding :)